# How to decide which PE can receive the interrupt in GIC

Tags: arm

When we set all irqs can be routed to all PE,how to decide which PE can receive the interrupt in GIC?
For example the first irq routes to PE0, the second routes to PE1, the third routes to PE2 and so on.

Explain the mechanism how the GIC choose the PE to handle the irq.